# Express time-step loops in Halide

Tags: halide

I am trying to implement the following loop nest in Halide

```
for (t = 0; t < TSTEPS; t++)
  for (i = 1; i < N - 1; i++)
     A[i] = (A[i-1] + A[i] + A[i + 1])/3;
```

But I couldn't figure out how to express the "t" loop since it doesn't contribute in the memory accesses. I went through the Halide tutorials but I couldn't find an example that illustrate such pattern.

Can you please show me an example of how to express such free loops in Halide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a two dimensional RDom:

```
Var x{"x"};

Param<int> N, TSTEPS;
RDom i {{{0, N}, {0, TSTEPS}}, "i"};

Func A{"A"};

A(x) = ...;
A(i.x) = (A(i.x-1) + A(i.x) + A(i.x + 1))/3;
```

The `TSTEPS` loop variable isn't mentioned in the update rule, but the loop will still be emitted. `i.x` refers to the `N` dimension, and `i.y` would refer to the `TSTEPS` dimension.

See this tutorial for more information: https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_09_update_definitions.html

Comment: Note: This is the right answer for anything that can be expressed as a single update stage like this. If you need to wrap such a time loop around a longer (multi-stage) pipeline, this needs to be done by one of two methods:

- Write a Halide pipeline for just the inner dimensions, then wrap the time loop around calls to that pipeline in C.
- If TSTEPS is small & constant, you can make a pipeline with that many iterations of the pipeline unrolled one after another.

Often the best answer is a combination, with small k unrolled steps and an outer loop in C of TSTEPS/k.